# How to detect if a binary raster bitmask and a polygon intersect using GDAL?

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, polygon, pygdal

I am wondering how to efficiently solve the following problem.  Given 1 bit georeferenced raster data that represents a bitmask, and a polygon - detect whether the area defined by the polygon covers any area with a set bit - as efficiently as possible.  I know I can rasterize the polygon, and "AND" it with the bit mask, produce an output image, and check if there are any set bits.  However - this seems inefficient; I don't need an output image, I just need to detect if there is *any* overlap between the area represented by the set bits of the raster, and the polygon as efficiently as possible.  I want to do this with open source software.

Comment: Might depend on your data, but two options to consider: do your polygons overlap? If they don't, just rasterise the polygons with an uniqueid, multiply by the mask, and get the unique values. If they do overlap, why don't you polygonise the mask and see whether the mask (now) vector overlaps the polygons? You can do either solution eficciently  with GDAL/OGR

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to rasterize your polygons, the other options is to make polygons from the raster mask. Here is an example using `rasterio.features.shapes` from the python rasterio package and with the following image and polygons. I used the all white cloud pixels as the binary mask, and detected whether the red polygons contained any clouds.
[image: rasterio test image with clouds]

```python
import numpy as np
import rasterio
import rasterio.features
import pyproj
from shapely.geometry import shape, MultiPolygon
from shapely.ops import transform


test_img_url = 'https://github.com/rasterio/rasterio/raw/master/tests/data/RGB.byte.tif'
with rasterio.open(test_img_url) as src:
    img_data = src.read([1,2,3])
    img_profile = src.profile

# Use the all white pixels, where all 3 bands are 255, of the 
# rasterio test images as the mask
masked_array = (img_data==255).all(axis=0)

# integer data type required by features.shapes
masked_array = masked_array.astype(np.uint8)

# features.shapes gives georeferenced polygons for continuous values of the same pixel value.
# Here pull polygons where the value=1 to match the cloud identification above.
# https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.features.html#rasterio.features.shapes
img_clouds = []
for img_shape, img_value in rasterio.features.shapes(masked_array, transform=img_profile['transform']):
    if img_value == 1:
        img_clouds.append(img_shape)

# Convert all the shapes to shapely objects, then to a single MultiPolygon
img_clouds = MultiPolygon([shape(s) for s in img_clouds])

def transform_shape_crs(shape, src_crs, dst_crs):
    """Transform a shapely shape to an arbitrary crs"""
    project = pyproj.Transformer.from_crs(src_crs, dst_crs, always_xy=True).transform
    return transform(project, shape)

# The original cloud polygons were in the image crs, so change to egps 4326
# to match the polygons for comparison
img_clouds = transform_shape_crs(img_clouds, src_crs = img_profile['crs'], dst_crs='EPSG:4326')

#---------------------------------
# Bring in the polygons to compare with. I drew these by hand.
primary_polygons =  [{ "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ 
                        [[ -78.261, 24.326 ], 
                         [ -78.382, 24.484 ], 
                         [ -78.247, 24.57 ], 
                         [ -78.126, 24.413 ], 
                         [ -78.261, 24.326 ]]]}, 
                    { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [
                        [[ -78.468, 24.956 ], 
                         [ -78.382, 24.957 ], 
                         [ -78.381, 24.901 ], 
                         [ -78.467, 24.9 ], 
                         [ -78.468, 24.956 ]]]} ]

primary_polygons = [shape(p) for p in primary_polygons]

#---------------------------------
# Now compare
primary_polygons[0].intersects(img_clouds) # True, contains clouds
primary_polygons[1].intersects(img_clouds) # False, contains no clouds
```